# Flutter: No host specified in URI https://

Tags: android, firebase, imagen, flutter

Tengo un boton en el que hay esta ***funcion***:

```
choose_imagen() async {
    final ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('Load Images/DSC_0280.jpg');
    var url = await ref.getDownloadURL();
    print(url);
  }
```

Tambien la ***instancia de firebase***:

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Firebase.initializeApp().whenComplete(() {
      print("completed");
      setState(() {});
    });
  }
```

Al darle al boton debe mostrarte una imagen de ***Firebase Storage***:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que esta dentro de una carpeta ***Load Images/***.
Al imprimir la url lo hace bien, pero me da un error y no la muestra.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo, he buscado y muchos dicen que deberia añadir `https://` pero lo he hecho y me sigue dando el ***error***.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: que URL te aparece en la consola cuando imprimes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error es por que al principio `url` esta vacio y el error te muestra sólo el esquema `https://` en `choose_imagen` necesitas hacer `setState` para actualizar el url.

```
final ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('Load Images/DSC_0280.jpg');
var u = await ref.getDownloadURL();
setState((){
  url = u;
});
```

Ademas de que `NetworkImage` debe de estar condicionada para que no se ejecute cuando el url esta vacio.

```
if (url != null && url.isNotEmpty) NetworkImage(....),
```

Answer (score 0):

El error indica que no estás proporcionando el Host de la Uri, comentas que estás agregando `https://` pero este es el protocolo, el Host debería ser por ejemplo:

```
www.stackoverflow.com
```

Verifica que la variable `url.toString()` contenga además del protocolo el Host. Una causa de este error puede ser que está variable no tenga valor.